# Can catalog value of @Table(name = "REVINFO", catalog= "another_catalog") be replaced by external config file's value?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-envers

Im using Hibernate Envers and created a custom REVINFO entity. The entity was:

```
@Entity
@RevisionEntity(AuditRevisionListener.class)
@Table(name = "envers_info", catalog = "another_catalog")
public class AuditEnversInfo extends DefaultRevisionEntity {

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private String userId;
}
```

My question is, how can I replace the value of catalog field on @Table annotation based on external config file such as application.properties value in SpringBoot?
I want it be dynamic so once I change the external config file to another catalog/schema, it will be automatically change its catalog/schema to persist the audited record.

Comment: Are you wanting that catalog config value to affect only this entity or all audited entities?

Comment: This entity and for all audited entities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Envers allows you to set this value via configuration by specifying one of two values, depending on your database platform's implementation.

```
org.hibernate.envers.default_schema
org.hibernate.envers.default_catalog
```

Since you have determined your database platform wants to use the *catalog* configuration rather than the *schema* configuration, then you simply need to provide this in your normal hibernate property configuration file as

```
org.hibernate.envers.default_catalog=another_catalog
```

You can define this configuration in a number of places

- In your `application.yml` or `application.properties` file used by `spring-boot`.
- In your spring application's java config for your `Session` or `EntityManager` factory.
- In a `hibernate.properties` file in the root of your application's class path.